# Back up uploads folder outside of wp-content?

Tags: uploads, backup

I've changed the default uploads location to mysite/media instead of wp-content/uploads because the url looks better.  That said, backup programs like WP Clone seem only to backup media when it's in wp-content/uploads.

Is it possible to backup the uploads folder wherever it may be within the installation?

Answer (score 1):

I use [BackWPup « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/) and it has an option to backup any folder in root, as well as the database and all other files. But it doesn't produce a one click restore file like some plugins.

Answer (score 0):

(Presuming here that you had the default uploads folder when you installed the plugin initially.)

Try deactivating and reactivating the plugin. It creates the backup folder when the plugin initializes. If you've changed the upload folder since installation of the plugin, it doesn't know where to put it.

> From: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/trunk/wpclone.php

```
register_activation_hook((__FILE__), 'wpa_wpclone_activate');

...<snip>....

function wpa_wpclone_activate() {
    wpa_create_directory();
    wpa_install_database();
}
```

Alternatively, you can manually create a directory called `/yourmediafolder/wp-clone` and backups should just work.